# save text value to listview & start count the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have TWO main questions that I really would have help with.
I have googled and searched for some day now without any help, but if you know any links that I maybe haven't watched or any site with help, then give me.
I would appreciated it, OR if you already have the code/sample code, would help :-)

I work with PhoneGap & JQuery Mobile right now, and the thing is this.
I have a 'textarea' there you write something, then a save button, what I want it to do is that when I press the save-button, the textvalue I wrote in the textarea would get saved in a listview in another page of the app. I have looked at "localstorage" but nothing works correctly.

(*Also, if you write something in textarea and you press the cancel button, the text in the textarea should be deleted next time you go in to that page.*)

The second question is:
When I press the save button, it should begin to count, in seconds, minutes, hours, days.
Think of it like this. I write "toothbrush" in the textarea and press save, now when I go to the listview-page, I can see it says toothbrush in the listview, beside the text it says 1m, 5m, 1h, it just update when it was last time I bought or changed the toothbrush, so next time I open the app, I can see "TOOTHBRUSH: 4Days, 16HRS, 52MINS AGO". In that way I can check when I bought something, or changed something.

This is my codes, both html & .js, what should I do so this mission will work.
Any suggestions, sites, or code you guys have that would help?

Thank you so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Last Time I Did It!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">            
            <h1>Last time I did it</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a data-role="button" href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="add" data-rel="page">ADD</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a data-role="button" href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="show" data-rel="page">SHOW</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div data-role="page" id="page2">
       <div data-role="header">            
           <h1>Add event</h1>
       </div>
       <div data-role="content">
       <textarea></textarea>
       </div>
       <div data-role="footer">
          <div data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                 <li>
                    <a data-role="button"  href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="save">SAVE</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <a data-role="button" href="#page1" id="cancel" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="page">CANCEL</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-role="page" id="page3">
      <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page2"  class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
        <h1>Events</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <ol data-role="listview" id="orderedList" data-inset="true"></ol>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
         <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" id="edit">EDIT</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" id="delete">DELETE</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my almost empty -js code.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
  $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){        
    $.mobile.navigate( "#page2", { transition : "slide", info: "info about the #bar hash" });
  });   
});

function save ()
{
   var fieldValue = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
   localStorage.setItem('content', orderedList);

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my new html & js file, after looked at your awesome code-example, but when I run it on my phone with phonegap, still, the save, cancel, the time and even the saved text will not show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Last Time I Did It!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">            
    <h1>Last time I did it</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"></div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="add" data-rel="page">ADD</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="show" data-rel="page">SHOW</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">            
    <h1>Add event</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <textarea id="newItemText"></textarea>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button"  href="#" data-transition="slide" id="btnSave">SAVE</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" href="#page1" id="btnCancel" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="page">CANCEL</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
    <h1>Events</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="orderedList" data-inset="true">
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" id="edit">EDIT</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-role="button" id="delete">DELETE</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS file.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page3', function(){ 
//setup the current list

if(localStorage.getItem('TaskList')){
    var TheList = [];
    TheList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
    var items = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < TheList.length; i++) {
        items += '<li><h3>' + TheList[i].text + '</h3><p>' + timeAgo( (new Date(TheList[i].time).getTime())/1000) + ' ago<p></li>';
    }

    $('#orderedList').empty().append($(items)).listview('refresh');

}

});


$(document).on('pageinit', '#page2', function(){ 

$('#btnCancel').on("click", function(){
    $('#newItemText').val(''); //CLEAR TEXT AREA
});

$('#btnSave').on("click", function(){

    var TheList = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem('TaskList')){
        TheList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
    }
    var newitem = $('#newItemText').val(); 
    var task = {text: newitem, time: new Date() };
    TheList.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('TaskList', JSON.stringify(TheList));

    $('#newItemText').val(''); //CLEAR TEXT AREA
    $.mobile.navigate( "#page3", { transition : "slide" });

});

});

function timeAgo(time){
var units = [
{ name: "second", limit: 60, in_seconds: 1 },
{ name: "minute", limit: 3600, in_seconds: 60 },
{ name: "hour", limit: 86400, in_seconds: 3600  },
{ name: "day", limit: 604800, in_seconds: 86400 },
{ name: "week", limit: 2629743, in_seconds: 604800  },
{ name: "month", limit: 31556926, in_seconds: 2629743 },
{ name: "year", limit: null, in_seconds: 31556926 }
];
var diff = (new Date() - new Date(time*1000)) / 1000;
if (diff < 5) return "now";

var i = 0;
while (unit = units[i++]) {
if (diff < unit.limit || !unit.limit){
  var diff =  Math.floor(diff / unit.in_seconds);
  return diff + " " + unit.name + (diff>1 ? "s" : "");
}
};
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

The JSFiddler code-example, the demo is perfect and are based on jQuery 1.9.1 & jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1, I used 1.6.4 & 1.1.0.
After updating this two .js files, everything worked on PhoneGap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6kM3B/1/)**

There are many questions within your problem, so I will probably not manage to answer all of them.  To use localStorage with an array of 'tasks' you use JSON.stringify when saving and JSON.parse when retrieving.

So, each time page3 is displayed, you retrieve the current list of items from localStorage, create list items, empty the list and then append the created items :

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page3', function(){ 
    //setup the current list    
    if(localStorage.getItem('TaskList')){
        var TheList = [];
        TheList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
        var items = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < TheList.length; i++) {
            items += '<li><h3>' + TheList[i].text + '</h3><p>' + TheList[i].time + '<p></li>';
        }

        $('#orderedList').empty().append($(items)).listview('refresh');    
    }    
});
```

When entering a new item, you want to store the text and the current time, so use an object.  First get the current list from localStorage, then create the new item and add it to the list, finally save back to localStorage clear the textarea and navigate to page3. The cancel button just clears the textarea:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page2', function(){ 

    $('#btnCancel').on("click", function(){
        $('#newItemText').val(''); //CLEAR TEXT AREA
    });

    $('#btnSave').on("click", function(){            
        var TheList = [];
        if(localStorage.getItem('TaskList')){
            TheList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TaskList'));
        }
        var newitem = $('#newItemText').val(); 
        var task = {text: newitem, time: new Date() };
        TheList.push(task);
        localStorage.setItem('TaskList', JSON.stringify(TheList));

        $('#newItemText').val(''); //CLEAR TEXT AREA
        $.mobile.navigate( "#page3", { transition : "slide" });    
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this demo and code examples. :-)
I looked at the code in the JSFiddler & compared to mine, changed the things so everything looks the same, but when I run phonegap on the phone, not save or time or cancel button will work like the one in JSFiddler. Need to look at the code again maybe & see what am doing wrong.

Comment: Where did the 'TaskList' come from? I made an EDIT in my first post, so you can watch the new updated code, but still, not working on my phone, but it works on JSFiddler

Comment: TaskList is just an array of the task objects. When you save it is JSON stringified and put into localStorage and when you go to page3 the JSON is retrieved from the same localStorage location and parsed back into the TaskList array.  I don't know phonegap, perhaps someone else can comment on using localStorage with phonegap...

Comment: I found the problem I had, it was very retarded problem that I didnt even see until today. Your JSFiddler demo is perfect, the thing is; you used jquery 1.9.1 and jquery mobile 1.3.0b1, I was using jquery 1.6.4 and mobile 1.1.0, after that I really looked at ALL code today, I realized the problem, after updating this .js files it worked. So thank you so much for your code and demo.