# Passing form data from one page to another html mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm new to mobile development and I am trying to pass information from a form and I want to display it on another page. I have tried passing the info using cookies but with no success..

Here is my code for the form:

```
function submit_jobs_post(){
      $.cookie('job_title', $('#job_title').val());
      $.cookie('job_des', $('#job_des').val());
      $.cookie('company_name', $('#company_name').val());
      $.cookie('company_address', $('#company_address').val());
      $.cookie('company_phone', $('#company_phone').val());
      $.cookie('company_email', $('#company_email').val());
}

<form method="post"  action="jobs_page.html" id="post_ads">   
  <label for="job_title">Job Title:</label>
  <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title">

  <label for="job_des">Job Description:</label>
  <textarea name="job_des" id="job_des"></textarea>

  <label for="company_name">Company Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name">

  <label for="company_address">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="company_address" id="company_address">

  <label for="company_phone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" name="company_phone" id="company_phone">

  <label for="company_email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="company_email" id="company_email" placeholder="Your email..">

  <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Post Job" onClick='submit_jobs_post()'>
</form>
```

And here is my code for the page to receive the information. When I submit the form the data does not appear on this page.

```
window.onload = function()
{               
      $('#job_title_got').val($.cookie('job_title'));
      $('#job_des_got').val($.cookie('job_des'));
      $('#company_name_got').val($.cookie('company_name'));
      $('#company_address_got').val($.cookie('company_address'));
      $('#company_phone_got').val($.cookie('company_phone'));
      $('#company_email_got').val($.cookie('company_email'));              
};

<input type="text" name="job_title_got" id="job_title_got">           
<textarea name="job_des_got" id="job_des_got"></textarea>              
<input type="text" name="company_name_got" id="company_name_got">        
<input type="text" name="company_address_got" id="company_address_got">
<input type="text" name="company_phone_got" id="company_phone_got">     
<input type="email" name="company_email_got" id="company_email_got" >
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance...

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to do this on the server side?

Comment: Should I use server side ? Sorry I'm new to this.  Orignally I just wanted  to get the data passed from the form page to the second page and  display data here.

Comment: There is no good way to do this on the client only since you would always have to rely on JavaScript.

Comment: When you say 'mobile' do you mean a single page app with multiple views?

Comment: I have multiple html pages on the app.

Comment: Instead of window.onload, use the jQM pagebeforeshow event (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) and instead of cookies, you can use localStorage ( example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062107/save-text-value-to-listview-start-count-the-time/21064516#21064516)